# Give all the permission to application in Android build

Tags: android

I am working on custom Android 11 project.

I want to grant all the permission to an specific application from Android source code.so that it hasn't been to ask user to grant permission.
Like setting application has all the permission.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: maybe take a look to "Grant all runtime permissions for testing purposes": https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#test-grant-all and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768081/how-to-grant-permissions-to-debugged-android-application

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 6, all permission must accepted by user.
IF you are owner device you can root your device, or add your app in to flash ROM. Or you can sign your app with the same key of your device. All method to auto grant perms is hard, cause we need protect users permission
[Fyi about perms](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)

Comment: thanks for the information, yes I have root device and can Add app in flash ROM. sign the app means give any signature to app right? like platform signature.@Jamebes